# Probability when selecting documents randomly

Tags: probability, random

## Setup

[Background context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801925/153407), see latest comment on answer dated 'Apr 30 at 20:46'.

You have documents $d_0$ to $d_{n-1}$ each randomly assigned an integer $k$ from the range [0, $2^{64}$), with a new value for $k$ randomly generated for each document.

The documents are arranged in order of lowest $k$ to highest, and in cases of the same $k$ value they are placed in lexicographical order by document name (document names are unique).

Documents are then selected randomly by

- randomly selecting $s$ from the range [0, $2^{64}$)
- randomly selecting a direction $C$ either $≥$ or $≤$
- Selecting document $d_s$ with a value for $k$ closest to $s$ in the direction $C$
- If there are no documents in that direction, repeat selection but with the other direction.

## Problem

Given $n > 2$ documents, an ideal distribution of $k$ values would result in the probably of selecting any document being as close to $P(d_a) = 1/n$ as possible.

What is the probably that $k$ values are selected such that the probability of $P(d_a) ≥ 2/n$?